# Showing GitLab profile picture on commits?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I use GitHub's desktop client to push and pull git GitLab, an alternative repository site that allows free private repos.

The issue is, when pushing to GitLab, it's not showing my profile picture as it is on GitLab, and its not linking my name to my profile, but to `mailto:email_here` ??

Can anyone assist with this.

Answer (score 14):

Check what is your current email with:

```
$ git config user.email
```

And set your email with

```
$ git config user.email "your.email@example.com"
```

Note that this will only affect new commits. Past commits will remain the same.

Comment: 1)Open Terminal.                                                                                                 
 2)Change the current working directory to the local repository where you want to configure the email address that you associate with your Git commits.

Comment: You can also add other email addresses to your GitLab profile under Settings -> Emails.

Answer (score 3):

You have to set the git mail attribute with your Gitlab login email address.
Run following command:

```
git config --global user.email "email@example.com"
```

Answer (score 0):

Go into your browser's settings and clear browsing data, which can include the cache, saved images